# Linux console perl replace not working on large file

Tags: regex, perl, ubuntu, replace

On ubuntu I'm running a console perl replace on a csv file of ~500MB. This is the call:

```
perl -i -pe 's/AS100\n/AS100/g' test.csv
```

Before run it on the complete file, I extracted a subset of it of ~30MB and run this script successfully.

When running on the full file, no substitution is done, and no error or message is showed.

I've tried also with sed, but the behavior is the same.

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: the extraction must have altered it. e.g.: check line endings.

Comment: is the -p flag needed, given it's in-place?

Comment: @Stygies yes, without it there's no implicit loop and no implicit print

Comment: Sorry for my dumb question but: did you wait long enough? I mean did the command return? Processing ½ GB of data can take quite a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying everything, I found out that in the original file the pattern was:

```
As100\r
```

and that the **\n** was a conversion done by Sublime Text when saving the test file.

So the correct code to do the trick was:

```
perl -i -pe 's/AS100\r/AS100/g' test.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have room, try to do this instead to look at the substitution as it is done to another file:

```
    perl -pe 's/AS100\n/AS100/g' test.csv | tee > test2.csv
```

My question is though, is it only the rows ending with AS100 that needs the newline removal?

Comment: The csv was an export from a db of an old server. There is a field that contains _AS100_ or is empty. After some unsuccessful imports, we find out that some of these values has a carriage return, and that it was impossible to manage this issue during the export phase